# Vague question regarding number of instances in a program

Tags: java, object

I have a question which I consider to be rather vague.

How many objects(instances) of class A are created by the following method:

```
void create() {
    A a;
    A b;
    A[] s;
    a = new A();
    b = a;
    s = new A[10];
}

class A { }
```

I am not sure how to count the array. We can easily see that the objects a and b are the same, but do we consider the array itself to be an object, or do we consider that it has 10 objects, which are null?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: The array is an object, but it's not an object of class A. You don't count the 10 null references of the array.

Comment: Only one object. this a = new A() Object of a class is only created when you call new operator and classname. String is an exception where you can create by double quotes.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s = new A[10]` is an object of A[], it's not an object of class A.

Therefore, you don't count the 10 null references of the array.

only `a = new A()` is created.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the above code through the Eclipse profiler and found that only one instance was created `a = new A()` which b also references. Hence there was only one instance created. The array of type A was not allocated as null until I assigned an object to the first index of the array. Hope this helps.